# Can the first person singular pronoun 'I' take in 's' in the simple present?

Tags: grammar, literature, grammaticality

I am quoting from The Memoirs of Sherlock Holmes, The Gloria Scott by Arhur Conan Doyle : "Thank you sir, said, the seaman, touching his forelock. I am just off a two-yearer in an eight-knot tramp, short-handed at that, and I WANTS a rest".
Is it just a spelling mistake (I am using a book from Wordsworth classics) or 'I' does take an 's' in some situations ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117209/discussion-on-question-by-aissam-can-the-first-person-singular-pronoun-i-take).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's slang, probably colloquial. A New England farmer might say "That fence wants some painting". Also, the author is trying to portray a person with little education, and this is illustrated by their misunderstanding the proper verb tense. In America you might hear someone say "She woke", or "She wake up a little while ago." English verb tenses are *hard*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! This isn't really an answer to the specific question, *"Can the first person singular pronoun 'I' take in 's' in the simple present?"*.  *"That fence wants* ... "* is normal grammar.  "I wants ... " is not. Also the OP didn't ask about the past tense.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Dust are our frames; and gilded dust, our pride
Looks only for a moment whole and sound;
Like that long-buried body of the king,
Found lying with his urns and ornaments,
Which at a touch of light, an air of heaven,
Slipt into ashes and was found no more.
--Tennyson 1793

Comment: With respect: How is that relevant to the the academic standard to which this forum as a whole aspires?  All games have rules - otherwise confusion results.  You may like to read the guidelines where it says, *"This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat... Ask questions, get answers, no distractions"* - https://english.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but I thought it was obvious that the phrase "I wants" is under scrutiny because of it's irregularity. I felt the premise was to prove if it was correct English or not which I felt that I addressed when called it "Slang". I never presumed that slang was proper just that it exists. Apologies.

Comment: No apologies needed - It took me a long time to get the hang of it here!  I still get pulled up now and again :-) As long as things remain dispassionate we muddle along amicably.